# Wheel center won't merge properly

Tags: modifiers

I'm new to blender and trying to do a wheel. But when i try to merge the center hub parts they dont..

[image: Center parts wont merge properly. I don't know why.. can anyone help me?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming all of your meshes are already combined to a single  mesh (if not please select all pieces and hit **Ctrl + J**).

Select and delete faces inside, as shown below:
[image]

Select the edge loops (as selected below) and follow the menu **Mesh->Edges->Bridge Edge Loops**:

[image]

Output will be :

[image]

I hope it will help you, best of luck :)